# If $\pi$ is parallel to $3i-4j$, how to find the vector equation of $\pi$?

Tags: calculus, vectors

A plane $\pi$ contains the line **r** = **i** + $3$**j** - **k** +$\lambda(2$**i** - **j** + **k**). If $\pi$ is parallel to $3$**i** - $4$**j**, how to find the vector equation of $\pi$?

I know that parallel planes have the same perpendicular vector. But I don’t seem to see how to find any normal vectors to the plane. I can’t cross product two lines, can I? So, how should I solve this question? Thanks

Comment: $3\hat i - 4\hat j$ is the normal vector.

Comment: What relationship must be true between a line in a plane and its normal?

Comment: Actually, I am wrong. I was thinking of two parallel planes that have the same normal vector. A vector parallel to a plane is in the plane so take the cross product. See the answer below.

Comment: See http://thejuniverse.org/PUBLIC/LinearAlgebra/LOLA/planes/vect.html

Comment: @JohnDouma Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the vectors $3i - 4j$ and $2i - j + k$ are parallel to the plane, so the normal vector of the plane is perpendicular to both of these vectors. We can find it using the cross product

$$r = \begin{array}{|c c c |} i & j & k \\ 3 & -4 & 0 \\ 2 & -1 & 1\end{array} = -4i-3j+5k$$

This gives us the equation of the plane as $-4x - 3y + 5z= c$ or $4x +3y -5z =d$. The point $i + 3j - k$ lies in this plane, so substituting these values gives us the value of $d$.

$$d = -4 -9 -5 = -18 $$

The equation of the plane is thus $ -4x -3y +5z = -18 $

Comment: The answer given is **r** $\cdot (-4$ **i** - 3**j** +5**k**) = -18

Comment: I think there’s a typo in the first line of the cross product, otherwise your answer would be the same as the book. Thank you

Comment: $(-i+8j-6k)\cdot(3i-4j)\ne0$, so this answer is incorrect. The second row of the matrix of which you compute the determinant is off.

Comment: I made a calculation error. Thanks for pointing it out!